# Laravel : How group by with select two column have deferent values

Tags: laravel, select, group-by

I want to group by table by name and select name and date, for name with same values have deferent valus of date, I tried this but don't work :

```
public function period(Request $req)
    {
        $absences = Absence::whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])->get();
        $daily = $absences->select('name ','date', 'COUNT(date) as counts');
        $arr['absences'] = $absences;
        $arr['daily'] = $daily;
        $arr['from'] = $req->from;
        $arr['to'] = $req->to;
        
        return $arr;
        return view('period',$arr,);
    }
```

I get error : `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select does not exist.`

and when I used this :

```
public function period(Request $req)
    {
        $absences = Absence::selectraw('name , date')->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])->groupBy('name')->get();
        $arr['absences'] = $absences;
        $arr['from'] = $req->from;
        $arr['to'] = $req->to;
        
        //return $arr;
        return view('period',$arr,);
    }
```

I get this :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'absences.absences.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select name , date from `absences` where `date` between 2021-10-02 and 2021-10-12 group by `name`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? I think the issue is you forgot to group by your selected (non-aggregate) columns.

```
$daily = Absence::query()
    ->select('name', 'date')
    ->selectRaw('count(date) as counts')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$req->from, $req->to])
    ->groupBy('name', 'date')
    ->get();

dd($daily);
```

Answer (score 0):

all column in select clause should be in gorup by too, this is the strict mode in mysql.
if you want to change it, go to config/database.php and set it to false:

```
  'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false, // instead of true
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```